# All of a sudden getting errors from Parse when using object with custom PFUser pointer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I've been killing myself for the past 48 hours trying to figure out what I changed and its driving me nuts!

I'm using a Parse database and I have 2 classes:

- User class which is a subclass of PFUser
- A Car class which is a subclass of PFObject

This Car class has a field "owner" which is a pointer to the User

Randomly 2 days ago I started getting this error when trying to save a new car or access and existing Car:

> 2016-01-14 20:18:04.135 YetiTest[3439:1130906] [Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "Key "firstName" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.":

firstName is a property of my User class but its populated. Today I also went back and checked versions of my code form before I started getting the error and now I'm getting the error there too. I'm really at a loss here... I'm new to programming and I'm pretty sure I'm doing other stuff thats bad practice, but it was working before so I dont get it! I'm including my class definitions below

Car

```
class ParseCar: PFObject
{
    @NSManaged var owner: PFUser?
    @NSManaged var make: String?
    @NSManaged var model: String?
    @NSManaged var year: String?
    @NSManaged var color: String?
    @NSManaged var licensePN: String?

init(owner: PFUser, make: String?, model: String?, year: String?, color: String?, licensePN: String?) {
    super.init()

    self.owner = owner
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.year = year
    self.color = color
    self.licensePN = licensePN
}


extension ParseCar: PFSubclassing
{

class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Car"
}

override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
}
```

user

```
class ParseUser: PFUser {

    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var zipCode: String?
    @NSManaged var userRole: String?
    @NSManaged var stripeID: String?
    @NSManaged var address1: String?
    @NSManaged var address2: String?
    @NSManaged var city: String?
    @NSManaged var state: String?
    @NSManaged var zip: String?
    @NSManaged var country: String?


    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the protocol `PFSubclassing` (see [Parse subclassing docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses)).

```
class ParseCar: PFObject, PFSubclassing { ... }
```

Just a heads up, I've run into really strange bugs using the Parse SDK in Swift because I registered the subclass in the `initialize` method (your milage may vary).

So call `ParseCar.registerSubclass()` when your app launches for the first time.

Comment: So in my initialize method for both classes I have self.registerSubclass. I should remove just that line from each class definition and in my app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method put ParseCar.registerSubclass and ParseUser.registerSubclass

Comment: If adding `PFSubclassing` doesn't work then try that yes.